# sftp limitation: disable chmod +x

Tags: sftp, chmod

Do I have an option to forbid a user group or a sftpuser to set chmod +x?

The user shall be allowed to upload media files, but no php scripts to run for example.

Comment: If the user has access to your machine then the user is able to run chmod. You could use AppArmor to prevent a syscall that is triggered by chmod but then it might destabilize you system. You can try and set the umask to the uploading directory as it suits you.

Comment: PHP scripts don't need to have the executable bit set to be interpreted (in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

Yes : You can use a dedicated partition for sftpuser.

Once done, just disable executables on this partition ("noexec" in /etc/fstab).

This would look like :

```
/dev/examplevg/sftpuser        /home/sftpuser                   ext3    defaults,noexec 1 2
```

Note that also have to chroot sftpuser and since sftpuser just needs to upload php files, it is also a good idea to restrict the account to sftp : [chroot + only sftp](https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh/354618#354618)