# Difference between OpenSSH internal-sftp and sftp-server

Tags: ssh, sftp

Why are there two ways to setup SFTP with OpenSSH and when to use which? Is there any difference between them?

I mean the first one is using a lib from OpenSSH and the second one says "use the internal", so it is also OpenSSH?

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Both `sftp-server` and `internal-sftp` are part of OpenSSH. The `sftp-server` is a standalone binary. The `internal-sftp` is just a configuration keyword that tells `sshd` to use the SFTP server code built-into the `sshd`, instead of running another process (what would typically be the `sftp-server`).

The `internal-sftp` was added much later (OpenSSH 4.9p1 in 2008?) than the standalone `sftp-server` binary. But it is used in the default configuration file now. The `sftp-server` is now redundant and is kept probably for backward compatibility only.

I believe there's no reason to use the `sftp-server` for new installations.

---

From a functional point of view, the `sftp-server` and `internal-sftp` are almost identical. They are built from the same source code.

The main advantage of the `internal-sftp` is, that it requires no support files when used with [`ChrootDirectory` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory).

Quotes from the [`sshd_config(5)` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand):

- For [`Subsystem` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Subsystem):

  > The command `sftp-server` implements the SFTP file transfer subsystem.
  >
  > Alternately the name `internal-sftp` implements an in-process SFTP server. This may simplify configurations using `ChrootDirectory` to force a different filesystem root on clients.
- For [`ForceCommand` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand):

  > Specifying a command of `internal-sftp` will force the use of an in-process SFTP server that requires no support files when used with `ChrootDirectory`.
- For [`ChrootDirectory` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory):

  > The `ChrootDirectory` must contain the necessary files and directories to support the user's session. For an interactive session this requires at least a shell, typically `sh`, and basic `/dev` nodes such as `null`, `zero`, `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`, and `tty` devices. For file transfer sessions using SFTP no additional configuration of the environment is necessary if the in-process sftp-server is used, though sessions which use logging may require `/dev/log` inside the chroot directory on some operating systems (see `sftp-server` for details).

Another advantage of the `internal-sftp` is a performance, as it's not necessary to run a new sub-process for it.

---

It may seem that the `sshd` could automatically use the `internal-sftp`, when it encounters the `sftp-server`, as the functionality is identical and the `internal-sftp` has even the above advantages. But there are edge cases, where there are differences.

Few examples:

- Administrator may rely on a login shell configuration to prevent certain users from logging in.  Switching to the `internal-sftp` would bypass the restriction, as the login shell is no longer involved.
- Using the `sftp-server` binary (being a standalone process) you can use some hacks, like [running the SFTP under `sudo`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su#sudo).
- For SSH-1 (if anyone is still using it), `Subsystem` directive is not involved at all. An SFTP client using SSH-1 tells the server explicitly, what binary the server should run. So legacy SSH-1 SFTP clients have the `sftp-server` name hard-coded.

Comment: "`internal-sftp` ... is used in the default configuration file now." No, it's not. From the man pages: "By default no subsystems are defined." From the default config included with the [openssh source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshd_config#L108): `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server`.

Comment: Here is the argument why `sftp-server` is the default: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3397
TL;DR: To separate the memory images, to protect the `sshd` parent process in case of an error in the SFTP server code.

Answer (score 8):

There exist alternative SFTP implementations that can be used together with OpenSSH:

- http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/sftpserver/
- https://github.com/mysecureshell/mysecureshell

Answer (score 6):

You can lock an authorized_key to the external sftp-server.

```
command="/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server" ssh-rsa AAAA…== user@host.com
```

When you do, your user can sftp, but cannot scp or ssh:

```
$ sftp host:/etc/group /tmp
Connecting to host...
Fetching /etc/group to /tmp/group
/etc/group                                    100%  870     0.9KB/s   00:00
```

Attempting to do anything else will just hang:

```
$ scp host:/etc/group /tmp
Killed by signal 2.

$ ssh host uptime
Killed by signal 2.
```

Alas, there is no easy way for a key to be locked to a chroot unless the sshd_config is modified. This would be really cool for a user to be able to do without the intervention of the system manager.

Comment: `ForceCommand internal-sftp` should achieve the same

Comment: Handy thing there is that without chroot you can use `sshfs host:/home/user/.ssh ~/hackme` to edit all those settings back to open access if you change your mind later.

Comment: the more important part of @sh1 's point is that if you're going to lock the user down to only sftp in _their own_ `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, you'd better make sure to chroot them somewhere that .ssh isn't accessible, or they can just replace their authorized_keys file with something more permissve

Comment: If all you want to do is lock an account to use SFTP only, just give their account the default shell /sbin/nologin

Comment: `chown root:group authorized_keys && chmod 0440 authorized_keys`

Comment: @MichaIng That's not safe either, because the user could just rename their `.ssh` folder to `.ssh_old` and create a new `.ssh` folder with a new `authorized_keys` file of their choice. Unless you also forbid them to change anything in their home directory, which might defeat the point or a home directory in the eyes of some people...

Comment: That's true. `chmod 0500 .ssh` maybe prevents against this. But what Phx says is probably the best approach: To lock the SFTP user into another sub directory via chroot. We use `ChrootDirectory` and `ForceCommand internal-sftp` (as described in the accepted answer) and the actual home directory of the SFTP upload user is owned by root with `0711` mode. This effectively locks the SFTP user into the chroot sub directory.