# How to set seprate current directory for sftp in macos?

Tags: ssh, ftp, mac-osx, unix, sftp

On my macos i am able to login to sftp as `sftp localhost`. When i run `!pwd` it shows me default directory is `/Users/username` but i want to change it `/Users/username/Sites/wordpress`.

I edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file & added below lines at bottom of file

```
Match User username
       X11Forwarding no
       AllowTcpForwarding yes
       PermitTTY yes
       PasswordAuthentication yes
       ChrootDirectory /Users/username/Sites/wordpress
```

But when i again try to login with `sftp localhost` after password prompt it gives me error as below

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

Please tell me how can fix this error ?

**EDIT:**

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftpr

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
Match User username
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    PermitTTY yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChrootDirectory /Users/username/Sites/wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure sshd to use `internal-sftp` for SFTP, not the old external sftp-server binary.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

The internal-sftp can use a chroot directory without requiring any supporting files to be placed in that directory.

You may also read about all the other [differences between internal-sftp and the old sftp-server](https://serverfault.com/q/660160/126632).

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @TechChain What did not work for you? What happened?

Comment: client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Connection closed

i get this error & i have edited my question

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Where i can check logs?

Comment: On the server, of course.

Comment: How to check logs ? i am new to this thing so i have less knowledge