# Disable intractive SSH depending on connection origin

Tags: ssh

Scenario:
Same users can connect from two different network segments to a ssh host. But they should not be able to use interactive ssh session when connecting from one (it's actually long-distance tunnels), only chrooted sftp should be allowed.

How can it be achieved? Is this achievable by sshd's  settings? Or by tcp wrapper (libwrap) + sshd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Match`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) directive at the bottom of  your `sshd_config` configuration file to override  global settings based on, among others, the **`Address`** users connect from.

That allows you to set a plethora of specific settings differently for specific users/groups/clients.

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# ... 
# your current global config
#
# Enable the internal sftp server

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

# ... 

# Override for users connecting from the 192.0.2.0/24 subnet
# They're only allowed to use sftp to their %h home directory

Match Address 192.0.2.0/24    
  ForceCommand internal-sftp 
  ChrootDirectory %h
```

See [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/660160/984089) for background on the internal-sftp server.