# Using internal-sftp for a single user instead of all users?

Tags: sftp, chroot

I am setting up a **restricted sftp** user with **chroot**, the standard procedure works fine for me, however I have existing users using sftp on the same server, and that's why I don't want to take a risk and change the default Subsystem "**sftp-server**" with "**internal-sftp**" for all users, I am wondering if skipping this step (step1 below) and only using the "**ForceCommand internal-sftp**" in the "**Match User**" block is enough (step2)? I already did some tests and it is looking fine, is there something I am missing?

This is the start of the procedure that I am following:

```
1 - Edit sshd_config. Comment the original "Subsystem" entry for sftp
    and replace it with the "internal-sftp" entry:

# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

2 - Add the following to the end of the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

Match User user99
        ChrootDirectory /chroots/%u
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        X11Forwarding no
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unless you’re one of the edge cases listed in https://serverfault.com/q/660160/37681 there is no reason to not use the internal sftp server (and some benefits)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ForceCommand internal-sftp` is sufficient to mandate the use of the internal sftp server in OpenSSH. In a `Match User` it only applies to that user. Note that `Match Group` is also an option, if a group that could match multiple users is desired.

`Subsystem` does not matter in this case. It may be there as an example that  `sftp-server` program is an alternative, or it might be someone understandably confused at this subtle difference of implementation choice.

With a new enough OpenSSH, my preference would be to use drop-in files, perhaps  `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`   Install  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/chroot.conf` or whatever, containing  with just the Match blocks defining the chroots.