# SFTP login accepted, SSH login denied by Synology NAS

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, network-attached-storage, synology

On a Synology NAS, I want to enable SFTP and SSH for some non-admin users.  (SSH mainly for pushing to git repos on the NAS.)

### What works

I was able to make SFTP work with different clients on Mac and Linux. The following is required to get this to work:

- In `/etc/passwd`, their login shell has to be changed from Synology's default `/sbin/nologin` to `/bin/sh` in a startup script
- "FTP" needs to be checked for the respective users in Disk Station Manager (Control Panel > Users > [User] > Applications > FTP). This seems to implicitly include SFTP.

### What doesn't work

Interestingly, SSH login via shell is denied:

```
$ ssh git@sectretnasdomain.com
git@secretnasdomain.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
Connection to secretnasdomain.com closed.
```

However, adding the users to the `administrators` group (not an option!) will make this command work. What can be the cause of that? As SFTP is built on top of SSH, this strikes me as odd.

### What I tried so far

- Made sure that the users' respective home directories configured in `/etc/passwd` have the proper permissions and owners.
- In Disk Station Manager

  - Add the users to "http" group
  - Give them permissions for all possible Applications in addition to "SFTP".
- In Package Center > Installed > Git Server > Open check "Allow access" for the uers
- In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, change `AllowTcpForwarding` to `yes` ("inspired" by [this related answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh)) and rebootet, making sure this setting was persistent

If relevant, my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has the following lines:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
AllowTcpForwarding no
ChrootDirectory none
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f DAEMON -u 000
Match User root
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
Match User admin
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
Match User anonymous
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    GatewayPorts no
```

Output of `ssh -vvv git@secretnasdomain.com`:

```
$ ssh -vvv git@secretnasdomain.com
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/XXX/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "secretnasdomain.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to secretnasdomain.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to secretnasdomain.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:73
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from secretnasdomain.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Hyi6ZdASC5SlabB0R3/pFWD06Xtn6IpeUfOkEf9wpHw
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:73
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from secretnasdomain.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:74
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
debug1: Host 'secretnasdomain.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:73
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa (0x564ec9526900), agent
debug2: key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to secretnasdomain.com ([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env GEM_HOME
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Permission denied, please try again.
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to secretnasdomain.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3020, received 3052 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 11227.8, received 11346.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Output of `sftp -vvv git@secretnasdomain.com`

```
$ sftp -vvv git@secretnasdomain.com
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/XXX/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "secretnasdomain.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to secretnasdomain.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to secretnasdomain.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:73
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from secretnasdomain.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Hyi6ZdASC5SlabB0R3/pFWD06Xtn6IpeUfOkEf9wpHw
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:73
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from secretnasdomain.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:74
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
debug1: Host 'secretnasdomain.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:73
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55986ce7aab0), agent
debug2: key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to secretnasdomain.com ([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env GEM_HOME
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
debug2: Remote version: 3
debug2: Server supports extension "posix-rename@openssh.com" revision 1
debug2: Server supports extension "statvfs@openssh.com" revision 2
debug2: Server supports extension "fstatvfs@openssh.com" revision 2
debug2: Server supports extension "hardlink@openssh.com" revision 1
debug2: Server supports extension "fsync@openssh.com" revision 1
Connected to secretnasdomain.com.
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:16 I:1
debug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> / size 0
sftp>
```

Comment: Show us output of `ssh -vvv git@sectretnasdomain.com` and `sftp -vvv git@sectretnasdomain.com` running on the same machine.

Comment: Authentication works: `debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).` `Authenticated to secretnasdomain.com ([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:22).` (it's not even technically possible that `ssh` cout not authenticate, if `sftp` can) – It's something else that fails later, but I was not able to identify what it was. Maybe something in some profile script?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Many thanks for the help! There is no `.bashrc` for the user. I added an echo statement at the top of `/etc/profile`, which gets executed for an admin user, but the git user never reaches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got unprivileged SSH access working with the following two steps:

1. Activate the unprivileged account in the Git Server package (see image below).
2. Change the login shell for the user in `/etc/passwd` to `/bin/sh`. This change will be undone when the NAS reboots, but a boot-up task can be created that makes this modification on each reboot (Control Panel > Task Scheduler > Create > Triggered Task).

```
USERS="some_ssh_user another_ssh_user"
for user in $USERS
do
    sed -i 's/^\('"$user"':.*\):[^:]*$/\1:\/bin\/sh/' /etc/passwd
done
```

Step 2. is optional if git access is sufficient. The login shell will be set to `/var/packages/Git/target/bin/git-shell` which does not allow full SSH access. However, modifying the login shell manually or with the above script won't work if the account is not activate in the Git Server package.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since this may help others... i had a similar issue, though with opposite behaviour as asked in this question: i could login via ssh, but not via sftp, resulting in errors like this one:

```
subsystem request failed on channel 0
```

It turned out the ‘application permission’ for the ‘FTP’ application (yes, also applicable to sftp) was disabled for my user. It can be enabled by editing the user account via the Synology DSM control panel.

Also make sure the SFTP service is actually enabled.

Comment: In my case, I also needed to enable SFTP Service in  Control Panel > File Services > SFTP > Enable SFTP service.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Git + /bin/sh hack doesn't survive a reboot.
However, if you don't plan to use Git, you can do this:

```
cd /var/packages/Git/target/bin/
mv git-shell git-shell-org
ln -sf /bin/sh git-shell
(and don't edit /etc/passwd)
```

Or at least it works with DSM 6.2.2-24922-3.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i just found out what the reason was for my "Permission denied, please try again.". Make absolutely sure any matching entry in your .ssh/config matches the actual synology server you are connecting to. So if your synology server is 192.168.2.6 on SSH port 3234, your entry in .ssh/config should be:

```
Host mysynology
   Hostname: 192.168.2.6
   Port: 3234
```

If your .ssh/config entry does not match the real situation, synology will reject the connection. Good luck!