# SFTP error on Synology DSM

Tags: sftp, synology, dsm

I created a user (no root), I can connect with him over ssh, I can send files over `scp` but when I'm using `sftp` I get this error:

```
subsystem request failed on channel 0
```

I checked `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# override default of no subsystems
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f DAEMON -u 000
```

I activated SFTP in "Files Services" > "FTP" > "SFTP" (FTP is not activated).

On my user properties I checked "FTP" in "Applications" tab, as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1001304/462049).

For information, I want to use `SFTP` to use it over Azure Pipelines Task [SFTP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops).

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: FTP != SFTP, make sure you enabled the correct one

Comment: Of course, I only activated SFTP but it is in same menu in WebUi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I changed my default port for SSH connection, and not for SFTP.

I had to set the same port for SFTP in my DSM configuration.

To get this conclusion, I checked sshd logs (started in interactive):

```
...
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req subsystem
debug1: skip sftp subsytem since sftp port is not matched
subsystem request for sftp by user MYUSER failed, subsystem not found
Connection closed by 192.168.X.X port 49430
...
```