# Can I seperate SCP and SSH login, using different ports and different users?

Tags: ssh, user-management, scp

I want to separate SCP to be on a different TCP port than the regular port 22.

Using this port, a user should only be able to run SCP commands but not to do a regular SSH login. That user would not have access to regular SSH login on port 22, and vice versa.

Is that possible?

Comment: Of course you can. But why would you want to, when you can [restrict a user to scp only](https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh)?

Answer (score 1):

Simply start a second ssh daemon with a separate [sshd_config](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) configuration file and you can run two instances of sshd, each configured differently.

Use for example the `Port customport` and `AllowUsers username1` keyword in one sshd_config  and login on your custom port is allowed only for the user `username1`.

In the other sshd_config use for example the `Port 22` and the `DenyUsers username1` keywords and login is disallowed on the default sshd port of 22 for the user `username1`.

---

AFAIK scp is plagued by a long history of security issues, and restricting  users to `scp` only access always seemed non-trivial and involve quite some work-arounds.

Therefore Red Hat is completely abandoning support for SCP as announced here: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/openssh-scp-deprecation-rhel-9-what-you-need-know  and now provides an `scp` that under the hood uses the SFTP protocol.

Limiting users to only SFTP is natively supported in OpenSSHd with the keyword:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

so that might be your best bet too.